# Active class not resetting

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

I created an active class so that when users pick answer choices, the background color of the answer choice would change and also it would give me the value of the button they selected. But the problem I am having is that when they get the correct answer, the second question comes but now it doesn't let you submit an answer. The active class stays at the last answer chosen and doesn't let you pick another. I created a GIF to show you the problem if my explanation is too confusing.

GIF - https://gyazo.com/ffcea635e246d50f222e3012e5ff58c6

Code:

```
<ion-view title="Quiz Question" hide-nav-bar="true">
    <ion-content padding="false" class=" manual-remove-top-padding" scroll="false">
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 1024px; height: 55px;"></div>
        <div id="quizContainer">
            <div>
                <p class="question-heading" id="question-heading"></p>
                <h2 class="question" id="question"></h2>
            </div>
            <div class="spacer" style="width: 1024px; height: 17px;"></div>
            <div class="answer-div">
                <button style="font-weight:600;font-size:28px;" id="a_one" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
                <button style="font-weight:600;font-size:28px;border-radius:5px 5px 5px 5px;" id="a_two" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
                
                <div class="spacer" style="width: 614.391px; height: 28px;"></div>
                
                <button style="font-weight:600;font-size:28px;" id="a_three" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
                <button style="font-weight:600;font-size:28px;" id="a_four" value="" class="button button-royal button-large button-outline answer-choices"></button>
                
                <div class="spacer" style="width: 614.391px; height: 29px;"></div>
                
                <button style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;" id="submit" class="button button-royal button-large button-block submit">SUBMIT</button>
                <button style="font-weight:500;font-size:28px;" id="submit-fake" class="button button-royal button-large button-block submit active"></button>                
            </div>
        </div>            
        <div class="spacer" style="width: 1024px; height: 29px;"></div>
        <div class="footer-div">
            <div class="spacer" style="width: 1024px; height: 25px;"></div>
            <div>
                <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/ionic-io-static/phJ5mlgnSieM31j8rIFh_Quiz_Icon01.svg" style="display: block; width: 4%; height: 4%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;">
            </div>
            <h1 style="color:#FAD75F;text-align:center;" class="h1">QUIZ</h1>
            <h1 style="color:#FFFFFF;text-align:center;" class="h4">SKILL LEVEL: Easy</h1>
            <button style="font-weight:500;" class="button button-light button-outline icon ion-android-home home-button"></button>
            <button style="font-weight:500;color:#FFFFFF;font-size:19px;" class="button button-light button-outline anotherquiz-button">SELECT ANOTHER QUIZ</button>
            <button style="font-weight:500;color:#FAD75F;font-size:22px;" class="button button-light button-outline icon-right ion-android-arrow-dropright nextq-button">NEXT QUESTION</button>
        </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Javascript

```
function ($scope, $stateParams) {       
    var currentQuestion = 0;
    var totalQuestion = questions.length;        
    var container = document.getElementById('quizContainer');
    var questionEl =  document.getElementById('question');
    var ans1 = document.getElementById('a_one');
    var ans2 = document.getElementById('a_two');
    var ans3 = document.getElementById('a_three');
    var ans4 = document.getElementById('a_four');
    var submit = document.getElementById('submit');
    var questionHeader = document.getElementById('question-heading');
    function loadQuestion(questionIndex){            
        var q = questions[questionIndex];
        questionEl.textContent = q.question;// grabbing the first question in the object
        ans1.textContent = q.answer1;
        ans2.textContent = q.answer2;
        ans3.textContent = q.answer3;
        ans4.textContent = q.answer4;
        // set answer choices to values
        ans1.value = q.answer1;
        ans2.value = q.answer2;
        ans3.value = q.answer3;
        ans4.value = q.answer4;
        questionHeader.textContent = questionIndex + 1 + '/10';            
    }
    
    // Add active class to the current button (highlight it)
    var btns = document.getElementsByClassName("answer-choices");
    for (var i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
        btns[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            var current = document.getElementsByClassName("active");
            current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");
            this.className += " active";
            answerChoosen = this.value;
        });
    }    

    submit.onclick = function() {            
        if(questions[currentQuestion].correctAnswer == answerChoosen){                
            alert("correct");
        }
        currentQuestion++;            
        loadQuestion(currentQuestion);
    }
    loadQuestion(currentQuestion);            
}
```

Question list

```
var questions = [{
    //1st object
    "question": "The first mechanical computer designed by Charles Babbage was called ?",
    "answer1": "Abacus",
    "answer2": "Analytical Engine",
    "answer3": "Calculator",
    "answer4": "Processor",
    "correctAnswer": "Calculator"
}, 
//2nd object
{
    "question": "Which of the following is the most powerful type of computer ?",
    "answer1": "Super-micro",
    "answer2": "Super conductor",
    "answer3": "Super computer",
    "answer4": "Megaframe",
    "correctAnswer": "Super computer"
}];
```

Comment: `current[0].className = current[0].className.replace(" active", "");` extra space before active

Comment: Please. PLEASE. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: You should remove the active class from the selected button when submit is clicked (or better - as part of loadQuestion), no use in pre-selecting an answer for the next question.  Does that make your initial problem go away?

Comment: Yes it did thank you, can you post your answer so I can vote it